# A question about arithmetic progressions and prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

I took number $3$ and observed:

$3$ is an arithmetic progression of length one.

$3,5$ is an arithmetic progression of length two.

$3,5,7$ is an arithmetic progression of length three.

Then I took number $5$ and observed:

$5$ is an arithmetic progression of length one.

$5,7$ is an arithmetic progression of length two.

$5,11,17$ is an arithmetic progression of length three.

$5,11,17,23$ is an arithmetic progression of length four.

$5,11,17,23,29$ is an arithmetic progression of length five.

So surely it would be nice to know:

> Is it true that for every prime number $p$ there exists $p$ arithmetic progressions, first of length one, second of length two, ... , $p$-th of length $p$ so that every of those arithmetic progressions has number $p$ as its first term.

I know about Green-Tao theorem but I do not know does this can follow from it or can the combination of Green-Tao theorem with some proven or unproven facts answer this question?

It is clear that with $p$ as a starting point we cannot have an arithmetic progression of primes with $p+1$ terms because $(p+1)$-st term would be $p+pd$ which is composite.

If this question has affirmative answer then we would have that for every natural $k$ we have an infinite number of arithmetic progressions of primes with $k$ terms so I guess that this is extremely hard but would like to hear opinions and suggestions for how could this be attacked.

Comment: Note that all you need is a single one of length $p$. The others could be initial parts of it.

Comment: @almagest Nice observation!!

Comment: @almagest But how do I know that there exist one of length $p$ that has number $p$ as its first term? Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: But this conjecture looks way beyond the limits of current knowledge to me. It is far stronger than the Green-Tao result.

Comment: All I am saying is that if you have a progression of length $p$ starting with $p$ as its first term, then by taking the first $k$ terms you get a progression of length $k$ starting with $p$ (for $k<p$).

Comment: @almagest Yes I see that, it is obvious.

Comment: @almagest Do you think that Green-Tao+de Polignac could answer this?

Comment: No, because it says nothing about the length of progressions starting with any particular prime. All it says is that somewhere in the primes you can find an AP of length $n$.

Comment: For $p=7$ you have $7,157,307,457,607,757,907$.

Comment: @ÁngelValencia Thanks. Very nice observation.

Comment: @Joffan What was the biggest step you looked at when you were trying to find sequence with 11 terms starting with 11?

Comment: Exploring up to $2000000$, the best arithmetic ratio for a prime arithmetic progression starting with $11$ is $1210230$, with $8$ consecutive primes. I still search a better ratio.

Comment: @Farewell Another slightly better sequence, we have reached 10-length, one step below the goal: $11 ,$ $224494631 ,$ $448989251 ,$ $673483871 ,$ $897978491 ,$ $1122473111 ,$ $1346967731 ,$ $1571462351 ,$ $1795956971 ,$ $2020451591$

Comment: Arithemtic primes and records: http://primerecords.dk/aprecords.htm#minimalstart

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/242613/a-question-about-arithmetic-progressions-and-prime-numbers

Comment: @GerryMyerson When I post a question from here to mathoverflow I post it with a link that the question is posted here. Should I do in future that what you did for me, to notify here that the question is posted on mathoverflow when I post it from here to there?

Comment: I think you should leave a link to the other site at each site, so that no matter where someone first sees your question, she will be aware that there might be further relevant information elsewhere.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you tell me why in your opinion there were not  any response to my question at mathoverflow, not even a single comment, did I ask something that I should not ask?

Comment: Be patient. MO goes a lot slower than m.se. But it might be that everything that can be said about the question has already been said here on m.se: everyone expects that for every prime $p$ there's a $p$-term arithmetic progression of distinct primes starting with $p$, but proving it is far beyond anything anyone knows how to do.

Comment: To reinforce Gerry's comment, we don't even know that a $3$-term progression exists for all $p$.  It's known to be true for infinitely many $p$, but not for all; proving that sounds roughly of the same difficulty as the infinitude of Sophie Germain primes, which is still open.

Answer (score 6):

Collecting my results together, there is a $7$-length sequence found for $7$:

$7,$ $157,$ $307,$ $457,$ $607,$ $757,$ $907$

Note that, starting at $11$ (or larger prime), to have a sequence of length $7$ or more it is essential that the step is divisible by $7\#=210$, to avoid multiples of the lesser primes, and in general for the $p$-length sequence from $p$, the step has to be divisible by the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) of the previous prime to $p$ (which could be written $(p-1)\#$, since only primes are multiplied anyway).

Best sequences to date for first 20 primes:
$$\tiny
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\text{Length} & & &\text{Longest sequence}\\ \hline 
2 \;\checkmark & 2 & 3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
3 \;\checkmark & 3 & 5 & 7 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
5 \;\checkmark & 5 & 11 & 17 & 23 & 29 &  &  &  &  &  \\
7 \;\checkmark & 7 & 157 & 307 & 457 & 607 & 757 & 907 &  &  &  \\
10 & 11 & 224494631 & 448989251 & 673483871 & 897978491 & 1122473111 & 1346967731 & 1571462351 & 1795956971 & 2020451591 \\
10 & 13 & 111739753 & 223479493 & 335219233 & 446958973 & 558698713 & 670438453 & 782178193 & 893917933 & 1005657673 \\
9 & 17 & 6947 & 13877 & 20807 & 27737 & 34667 & 41597 & 48527 & 55457 &  \\
10 & 19 & 35707369 & 71414719 & 107122069 & 142829419 & 178536769 & 214244119 & 249951469 & 285658819 & 321366169 \\
9 & 23 & 100613 & 201203 & 301793 & 402383 & 502973 & 603563 & 704153 & 804743 &  \\
9 & 29 & 8456519 & 16913009 & 25369499 & 33825989 & 42282479 & 50738969 & 59195459 & 67651949 &  \\
10 & 31 & 104816281 & 209632531 & 314448781 & 419265031 & 524081281 & 628897531 & 733713781 & 838530031 & 943346281 \\
10 & 37 & 2040607 & 4081177 & 6121747 & 8162317 & 10202887 & 12243457 & 14284027 & 16324597 & 18365167 \\
9 & 41 & 19489511 & 38978981 & 58468451 & 77957921 & 97447391 & 116936861 & 136426331 & 155915801 &  \\
9 & 43 & 52963 & 105883 & 158803 & 211723 & 264643 & 317563 & 370483 & 423403 &  \\
9 & 47 & 3025307 & 6050567 & 9075827 & 12101087 & 15126347 & 18151607 & 21176867 & 24202127 &  \\
9 & 53 & 15441983 & 30883913 & 46325843 & 61767773 & 77209703 & 92651633 & 108093563 & 123535493 &  \\
9 & 59 & 49267739 & 98535419 & 147803099 & 197070779 & 246338459 & 295606139 & 344873819 & 394141499 &  \\
9 & 61 & 27388681 & 54777301 & 82165921 & 109554541 & 136943161 & 164331781 & 191720401 & 219109021 &  \\
9 & 67 & 48175117 & 96350167 & 144525217 & 192700267 & 240875317 & 289050367 & 337225417 & 385400467 &  \\
9 & 71 & 13959401 & 27918731 & 41878061 & 55837391 & 69796721 & 83756051 & 97715381 & 111674711 &  \\
\end{array}
$$